# Windows File Explorer equivalent for Awesome bar

Tags: windows-7, firefox, windows-explorer

Firefox has a very handy feature, the [Awesome bar](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Location%20bar%20autocomplete):

> Just type a few letters of a website’s name or address into the location bar and it will find it for you. And the more you use it, the better it gets.

For me, it has substituted use of bookmarks. It's more efficient to start writing the title of some web page in the Awesome bar than start checking whether I have saved the page a bookmark or not.

Is there some way to make Windows File Explorer behave the same way, providing auto-complete and learning about my behavior?
If not, are there then any 3rd party applications which would offer the awesomeness of the Awesome bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one I've been using before has been [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/), but I stopped using it after I got used to Windows 7 Start menu lookup. It works decently well, only not for files, but still can be configured.

About Launchy, it is mostly intended for executable files, but you can tweak its settings to look for any type of file you like. It works decently fast as well.

Comment: Can upvote anymore today.. was tto generous, wish others were too.. but +1 in theory for Windows 7 Search! Awesome.. launchy was also good. Besides, Chrome has that built in..

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks! I personally think Chrome's one is better, it seems to learn faster your common searches (or at least I think so). Launchy works more on a _last-input-is-better_ approach so it isn't really learning (is it?) but still useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Windows File Explorer's advanced search](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/exploring-vistas-advanced-search.html), easily brought up with CTRL + E, is something that can be used if you don't want to install 3rd party applications.

Windows Search is a bit clumsy, though: when you want to launch the first result after a successful search, you have to press Esc (to dismiss search filter), Down arrow, Space (to select the result) and finally Enter (to launch it).